# Meaning of "gamecock" when referring to a person

Tags: meaning, slang

I was watching a south korean drama (Youth of may), second episode, and the scene is:

The guy is waiting at the restaurant for a blind date. The girl arrives late and as soon as she seats in front of him, he says: Gamecock.

The guy and the girl are wearing suits. I already looked into dictionaries, but the meanings I've found doesn't seem to match. The only one would be from urban dictionary:

4.)Someone who, after starting a fist fight with themselves, could still find a way to lose.

But also, it doesn't seem like that's the meaning.

Comment: What's the name of the video?

Comment: Was she wearing any University of South Carolina merchandise?

Comment: south korean drama (Youth of may), second episode

Comment: Gamecocks are fighting cocks. They have sharp metal spurs attached to their feet and people bet on which bird will kill the other. It's been illegal in the UK since 1835 but has never died out. Does the woman look ready for a scrap?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian No, she doesn't look ready for a scrap.

Comment: Merriam-Webster Online's definition of [_gamecock_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gamecock) is simply "a rooster of the domestic chicken trained for fighting." As far as I know, there is no widespread alternative meaning of _gamecock_ in English slang that a Korean translator is likely to have latched onto.

Comment: I have two questions: 1) Is there a Korean idiom which could be translated literally as "gamecock" that would make sense in the context and 2) What was the tone of voice used?

Comment: Given the context ( a South Korean drama) it's quite possible that ***gamecock*** here is simply a ***misuse***. The word really has little currency among mainstream native Anglophones, and anything in Urban Dictionary is likely to be worthless anyway. Perhaps the guy thought he might have been "stood up" (by his late / no-show date) and he really should have labelled her a ***cock-teaser***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here, maybe gamecock means tough opponent/rival or somebody that is a fierce fighter in a game, relationship and so on.